# Show Attribute of Relation in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I want to show the attribute of a relation in a DataGridView. I use LINQ to SQL to do the mapping and have the following classes:

```
class Computer
{
    public string Name;
    public User User;
}

class User
{
    public string Name;
}
```

I use a DataGridView to show some rows of the `Computer` entity and also want to have one column to show the name of the user associated with this computer.

I've created an object data source of the `Computer` class. I've set the `DataSource` property of my BindingSource to this data source and linked my DataGridView with this BindingSource. I've added a column to my DataGridView and set the `DataPropertyName` property to //User.Name//, but this does not work. What is a good way to do this?

I've already thought about creating an additional class which inherits from `Computer` and has an additional string property which represents the name of the user; but I want to avoid this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var computerUsers = from c in mydataContext.Computer
select new {
 computerName = c.Name,
 userName = c.User.Name
};

myDataGridView.datasource = computerUsers;
myDataGridView.dataBind();
```

and in your datagridview call "computerName" and "userName"

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="computerName" HeaderText="Computer" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="userName" HeaderText="User" />
```

Comment: I've already thought about the solution with anonymous classes, but I like to use the GUI Design if possible.

Comment: What code do you want exactly? I use the GUI designer to position my controls, do you want to code the Designer has generated?

Comment: oops.did not see the windows-forms tag.Does it work the same as web-forms? like a aspx file and a code behind file?Sorry.Not familiar